# Ionic cordova run browser equivalent for Capacitor project

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native, capacitor

I’m trying to play an audio for all the platforms, but in browser I got the following message:

[image: warning]

common.js:284 Native: tried calling NativeAudio.play, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator

The solutions I found in google says that I should use the following comand:

-ionic cordova run browser

But I’m using Capacitor and it refuses to use the command inside the Capacitor project.

My question is.

Do I need to make another implementation to play audio in browsers or I can just keep things this way and use some kind of command to run this NativeAudio in browsers?

More information:

The library I’m using is: @ionic-native/native-audio/ngx

The method I’mCalling is nativeAudio.play(…)

Comment: It would help if you shared your code.

Comment: Or just start over and make it a Cordova project. :-D .... have you tried "npx cap serve"